# Regex (Javascript) - Match certain chat queries

Tags: javascript, regex

So I'm posting due to me having spent several hours working on a filter that should record only certain chat messages based on the start of said message. I've reached a point where it's about fifty-fifty, but my lack of knowledge regarding regex has stopped me from being able to continue working on it.

Basically, the expression is *supposed* to match with messages that are one of a few annoying things. My apologies if this gets too specific, I'm unsure of how to get all of the conditions working together.

1. *"word":*  (any word that is not "notice" or "type: s" - So anything like *John:*
2. *word*_*word*: (this time, the second word can be anything) - Something like *John_Smith:*
3. [Tag]*word*: or [Tag]*word*_*word*: (where a tag is either a unicode character or two characters between square brackets) - Something like *[DM]Tom_Cruise:* or such
4. One of the above, minus the colon. This is where I'm having issues. Something like *[DM]Tom_Cruise waves.*
5. Starts with (WHISPER) or (SHOUT). It doesn't matter what comes after it, in this case.

I've managed to get a regex that works with most of the situations, but I can't get condition **4** to work without getting unwanted messages. 
In addition, if the message (received as a string per line) starts with *(OOC)*, it shouldn't be matched. If it says *(OOC)* in the message later on, it's alright. If the string ends with "joined the game." or "left the game.", it should also not match.

So... yeah, I'm completely stuck on getting condition 4 to work, and hoped that the community that helped me get this far wouldn't mind answering a (hopefully not too specific) question about it. Here's the expression as I've gotten it:

```
(?!^\(OOC\))(_[a-z]+:)|(^[a-z]+:)|(^[a-z]+ [a-z]+ )
```

It can match most of the above conditions, except for **4** and some of **1**. I can't figure out how to get the specific words (notice: and type:s) to not match, and 4 is just messing up some of my other conditions. And lastly, it doesn't seem to stop matches if, despite starting with (OOC), the string matches another condition.

Sorry if this is too specific, but I'm completely stuck and basically just picked up regex today. I'll take anything.

**EDIT**

Examples:

- [AT]Smith_Johnson: "Hello there." *- matches under Condition 3, works*
- Tom_Johnson: moves to the side. *- matches under Condition 2, works*
- Notice: That private wooden door is locked. *- should not match due to Condition 1, but currently does*
- Tom hops around like a fool. *- Should match under Condition 4, doesn't*
- (OOC)SmithsonsFriend: hey guys, back *- matches, but shouldn't under the not-match specifiers*
- (WHISPER)Bob_Ross: "Man, this is lame." - Condition 5
- West Coast: This is a lovely place to live. *- doesn't match due to whitespace, that's good*
- Joe joined the game. *- matches, shouldn't under the not-match specifiers*

**EDIT TWO**

To clarify:

A) string starts with (OOC) - **never** match

B) string starts with (WHISPER) or (SHOUT) - **always** match

If neither A nor B apply, then go to conditions 1-4.

Comment: Post some valid and invalid examples. (for each of the 4 conditions separated be great)

Comment: where in your current regex are you excluding the words "notice" and "type"?

Comment: I've added some example now, my bad. Currently, I don't have a way set up to exclude "notice: " and "type: ", since everything I tried either did nothing or broke everything else.

Comment: What is the difference between `Tom hops around like a fool` and `Joe joined the game.` and what is the difference between `(OOC)SmithsonsFriend: hey guys, back` and `(WHISPER)Bob_Ross: "Man, this is lame`?

Comment: The main difference is the context. "Joe hops around like a fool" is an action, while "Joe: "Hello!" is a piece of dialogue. Similarly, any string that starts with (WHISPER) or (SHOUT) is one of those two. "Joe joined the game" or "(OOC)SmithsonsFriend: hey" are both messages sent into the chat that I don't want matched to avoid spam.

Comment: So, `(WHISPER)` and `(SHOUT)` should be white listed? This solves the first thing, but how would you technically differ between `Joe hops around like a fool` and `Joe joined the game`? Are you here also thinking about a white list? What should exactly match and what not? `[A-Z]* joined the game`?

Comment: "[A-Z]* joined the game" and "[A-Z]* left the game" was pretty much exactly how I was planning on doing it. As for a whitelist... I'd probably consider it if I knew more about regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regular expression:

```
^(?:\(shouts\)|\(whisper\))?(?:\[[A-Z]{1,2}\])?(?!Notice|Note)[A-Za-z]*(?:_[A-Za-z]*)?(?::|\s(?![A-Za-z]*:))(?!(?:joined|left) the game)
```

- `^` Start of the string (make sure to check line by line)
- `(?:\(shouts\)|\(whisper\))?` allows optional sequences like `(shouts)` or `(whisper)`
- `(?:\[[A-Z]{1,2}\])?` matches a non-capturing group with 1 or 2 `A-Z` characters inside `[]` which is optional (because of the `?` at the end)
- `(?!Notice|Note)`: list of words, which are not part of the subsequent selector
- `[A-Za-z]*` matches as much alphabetical characters as possible
- `(?:_[A-Za-z]*)?` matches a `_` followed by alphabetic characters
- `(?::|\s(?![A-Za-z]*:))` matches a `:` or a whitespace character `\s`, which however cannot be followed by `[A-Z]:`
- `(?!(?:joined|left) the game)` negative lookahead: whole regex does not match, if this pattern matches

*You should add the case insensitive flag `/i` in your regex, if you want to e.g. match `(whisper)` and `(WHISPER)`.*

*→ Here are your example texts in an **updated** [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/H5RdLP/4) for a live test*

Comment: This is nearly perfect, thanks! The only problem is, strings under Condition 4 don't seem to be working. Also, I missed something at the start - editing it into the main question. Basically, if it starts with (whisper) or (shout), it should match. Sorry for the problems, completely forgot about that part.

Comment: @throwAwayOfShame1361 I've updated the regex and the [`regex101`](https://regex101.com/r/H5RdLP/3) live test. If it works, you can upvote and accept (✔ on the left) the answer.

Comment: This is almost exactly what I want, but there's a small issue. Currently, it allows something like "West Coast: This is a lovely place to live." It should only allow the words before the colon to have underscores between them. Other than that, it's perfect. Thanks! (also yeah, it's case insensitive, no worries.)

Comment: It is not possible to match `Tom hops around like a fool` and not match `West Coast: This is a lovely place to live.` if you are not defining exceptional cases like for `left the game`.

Comment: Is it not? I was hoping that since statements like that are always two words followed by a colon, something could be done. If not... thanks for the help, it's more than good enough for what I need.

Comment: It is, if there are only two words before the colon. But those could be anything like `He said: I want to go out`

Comment: @throwAwayOfShame1361I have updated it again ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/H5RdLP/4)). It also does now not allow two consecutive words (space separated) followed by a `:`

Comment: Wow, thanks a ton! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making it one big (**HUGE**) regular expression, you could make a function that take a message and then check it against a number of regular expression (much flexible and much easier to implement). Like this:

```
function isValid(msg){
    // starts with "WHISPER" or "SHOUT"
    if(/^(?:whisper|shout)/i.test(msg)) return true;

    // Check if it begins with "notice:" or "type:"
    if(/^(?:notice|type)\s*:/i.test(msg)) return false;

    // Check if it ends with "joined the game" or "left the game."
    if(/(?:joined|left)\s+the\s+game\.?$/i.test(msg)) return false;

    // starts with "(ooc)"
    if(/^\(ooc\)/i.test(msg)) return false;

    // "[at]word:" or "[a]word_word" or "word:" or "word_word" ...
    if(/^(?:\[[a-z]{1,2}\])?[a-z_]+:?.*$/i.test(msg)) return true;

    return false;
}
```

**Example:**

```js
function isValid(msg) {
  if (/^(?:whisper|shout)/i.test(msg)) return true;
  if (/^(?:notice|type)\s*:/i.test(msg)) return false;
  if (/(?:joined|left)\s+the\s+game\.?$/i.test(msg)) return false;
  if (/^\(ooc\)/i.test(msg)) return false;
  if (/^(?:\[[a-z]{1,2}\])?[a-z_]+:?.*$/i.test(msg)) return true;
  return false;
}

function check() {
  var string = prompt("Enter a message: ");
  if(isValid(string))
    alert(string + " is valid!");
  else
    alert(string + " is not valid!");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="check()">TRY</button>
```

Comment: Honestly, I'd vastly prefer to do it that way. But I need to enter it as a single expression due to the way that the mod in use works. It needs to be entered as a single regex expression. Thanks, though!